# When trying to use the sum command on a large number of rows, I get an incorrect answer. How do I properly sum these numbers?

Tags: bash, sum

I have several files with a large number of rows and I'm interested in finding the sum of the numbers in the sixth column of this file.

Currently I use the following series of commands:

`cat file.txt | cut -f 6 | sed "1d" | sum`

And it outputs:

`01667     4`

Obviously I know this answer is wrong (when I copied everything into excel and used that sum function it gave me an answer of 21693) and I know it has something to do with calculation issues inherent in the language, but I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. There are a total of 1452 individual numbers that I am trying to sum from that one specific file (I would like to do it on several similar files that will have similar numbers of rows as well).

Can anyone assist in helping me figure out the issue to this problem?

Comment: Have you tried `man sum` ? `sum` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: You should post a snippet of the input format and an example of what you want the output to look like. As M. Nejat Aydin said, `sum` isn't what you think, and so isn't the tool you want. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ - but I will post you a solution, I think we can still help.

Comment: I did spend several hours trying to figure this out by searching posts on stackoverflow before I posted a question here, but I do not have a background in computer science. I'm sorry if I missed something obvious.

Comment: Just always look at the usage instructions of your tools when they aren't doing what you expect. It's not a judgment on you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$: sum --help
Usage: sum [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Print checksum and block counts for each FILE.
```

`sum` isn't what you want.

Also, `cat` to `cut` to `sed` to something else is often an indicator that you're overdoing something. c.f. [this link](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award), and more importantly, [this one](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/119).

Take a look at [`awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html), which can handle all that in one call. (You might not have GNU awk.)

```
awk 'NR>1{tot+=$6} END{print tot}' file.txt
```

That should handle it efficiently.

As an aside, *if* you are skipping row 1 because it's headers, and IF they are just strings, you can *probably* remove the test for NR on every row, as the string will (be careful) usually evaluate mathematically to zero. I don't like doing things that way, but there is a school of thought that says simpler is always better. YMMV.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. The header is a string, so I will try removing the NR qualification and give that a shot as well. Much appreciated.